# Excluir registro com Laravel via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, sweetalert

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em PHP com Laravel e tenho no meu AlunosController e seguinte método destroy:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $aluno = new Aluno();
    $result = $aluno->find($id)->delete();

    if($result)
        return redirect()->back();
    else
        return 'Falha';
}
```

Até aí tudo bem, a função funciona corretamente. O problema é que decidi usar o SweetAlert para fazer o meu confirm antes da exclusão. Ficou assim:

```
var btnExcluir = $('.btn-danger');
btnExcluir.click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title: "Deseja continuar?",
        text: "O cadastro do aluno será excluído permanentemente!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Sim, excluir!",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/alunos/destroy",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id: 8
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function () {
                swal("Excluído!", "O cadastro do aluno foi excluído com sucesso.", "success");
            }, error: function(){
                swal("Erro!", "Não foi possível remover o aluno.", "error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Passei o id 8 fixo apenas para teste com um registro que eu tenho, mas está sempre caindo no error.

Já tentei passar o id na url, tentei usar o type DELETE, tentei passar ID_ALUNO_ALU (que é o nome do atributo no banco de dados e no model) em data ao invés de id e nada funcionou. Alguém que já tenha usado AJAX no Laravel poderia me dar uma luz?

Para adiantar, a parte que interessa da minha view está assim:

```
@foreach($alunos as $aluno)
<tr>
    <td>{{$aluno['NM_NIS_ALU']}}</td>
    <td>{{$aluno['ST_NOME_ALU']}}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{$aluno['IDADE']}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">
        {!! Form::open(['route' => ['alunos.destroy', $aluno['ID_ALUNO_ALU']], 'method' => 'delete', 'class' => 'form']) !!}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs esconder-acao" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAluno{{$aluno['ID_ALUNO_ALU']}}">Editar</button>
            {!! Form::submit('Excluir', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs esconder-acao']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Como farei para passar o id do aluno para o js?

Valeu galera!

Comment: Tente trocar dataType: "html" para dataType: "JSON"

Comment: "mas está sempre caindo no error" isso no JavaScript, certo? E no PHP, o que acontece? O registro é devidamente excluído do banco de dados?

Comment: Não apaga não. Descobri que o data não está chegando no destroy, mas ainda não sei porque

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente, você definiu no seu arquivo de rotas o verbo "delete" para a rota específica, já que no seu formulário você definiu esse method. Quando você executa a ação no Ajax, a requisição está indo como post. Se não há um post esperando nessa rota, você vai receber um erro de rota não encontrada. Mude o dataType para JSON e o método da requisição para "delete".

O Laravel tem um recurso para trabalhar com verbos HTTP "não oficializados", que é colocar um campo escondido com o nome _method no formulário, para trabalhar com métodos de DELETE, por exemplo. Faça o mesmo no campo de dados da sua requisição.

Comment: O autor especifica que tentou utilizar `type: "delete"` na requisição AJAX. É isso que você está sugerindo?

Comment: Além de colocar o type: "delete", colocar no data uma chave _method: "delete", que é a forma padrão que o Laravel lida com formulários que utilizam esse verbo e outros, como PUT

Comment: Já tentei tudo isso aí. Estou usando um Controller Resource então minha rota é resource também

Answer (score -1):

Você cometeu 3 erros: a URL da requisição AJAX está errada pois deve conter o segmento relativo ao ID do aluno; você não está informando a chave `_method` com o valor `DELETE` no objeto `data`; o `dataType` que você espera receber é do tipo `json` e não `html`. Também não há necessidade de informar o ID do aluno no objeto data se essa informação já vai estar contida na URL e a utilização do evento `click` nos elementos que tiverem a classe `.btn-danger` foi uma má escolha visto que só dificulta a obtenção dos dados do formulário.

```
$('.form-aluno-delete').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('url'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function () {
            swal("Excluído!", "O cadastro do aluno foi excluído com sucesso.", "success");
        }, error: function(){
            swal("Erro!", "Não foi possível remover o aluno.", "error");
        }
    });
});
```

});

```
@foreach($alunos as $aluno)
<tr>
  <td>{{$aluno['NM_NIS_ALU']}}</td>
  <td>{{$aluno['ST_NOME_ALU']}}</td>
  <td class="text-right">{{$aluno['IDADE']}}</td>
  <td class="text-center">
    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['alunos.destroy', $aluno['ID_ALUNO_ALU']], 'class' => 'form-aluno-delete']) !!}
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs esconder-acao" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAluno{{$aluno['ID_ALUNO_ALU']}}">Editar</button>
      {!! Form::submit('Excluir', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs esconder-acao']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Existe a necessidade do `input` com o nome `_mthod` apenas se utilizar o `submit` do formulário, não? Se utilizado AJAX, o método pode ser definido diretamente como `DELETE`, visto que o jQuery oferece suporte para tal método.

Comment: Não, esse campo é necessário, pois é essa informação que dirá ao Laravel utilizar o método DELETE invés de POST no momento de buscar pela rota correspondente. Você pode também apagar esse campo e passar essa informação diretamente na key data nas options da requisição ajax.

Comment: Foi exatamente o que eu disse xD

Comment: Sim, desculpe! Se passar diretamente na key `method` não precisará desse do campo na view, mas precisará provavelmente do campo `csrf_token` que esqueci de colocar, a n'ao ser que tenha desativado esse middleware.